# Removing specific value from list of key value pair from Dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Below is the dictionary set I have

```
dict = {'city':[('hyderabad','pune','chennai'),'state':[('Telangana','mumbai','tamilnadu')]}
```

I'm trying to remove the first two strings from the list in key value pair from this dictionary, so it will look the same as below

```
dict = {'city':[('chennai'),'state':[('tamilnadu')]}
```

I have tried:

```
for v in dict.values():
    del v[0:1]
```

but this deletes the whole list instead of first two indexes, need help in deleting only the first two indexes of each value list in key value pair

Comment: Please refrain from using pandas for trivial data structure manipulations like these.

Comment: This is not related to pandas, removing the tag

Answer (score 3):

You can use list slicing:

```py
dct = {
    "city": [("hyderabad", "pune", "chennai")],
    "state": [("Telangana", "mumbai", "tamilnadu")],
}

dct = {k: [l[2:] for l in v] for k, v in dct.items()}
print(dct)
```

Prints:

```py
{
 'city': [('chennai',)], 
 'state': [('tamilnadu',)]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dictionary = {
   'city':[('hyderabad','pune','chennai')],
   'state':[('Telangana','mumbai','tamilnadu')]
}
dict_new = {}
for key, value in dictionary.items():
  dict_new[key] = [value[0][2:],]

print(dict_new)
```

Or, if you prefer to use comprehension notation...

```
dict_new = {key: [value[0][2:],] for key, value in dictionary.items()}
print(dict_new)
```

Output:

```
{
   'city': [('chennai',)], 
   'state': [('tamilnadu',)]
}
```

Btw.. Try don't use reserved words like `dict`, `tuple`, `str`, etc. like variables names